# WebKit reduces table cell size when filled with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, webkit

I have a table here that displays an icon, title, a description. Here's it schematically:

```
      | Title
 icon | -------------------
      | Description
```

Here's the relevant HTML code that generates this layout:

```
<table><tbody>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"><img style="margin-right: 2.0em;" src="icon.png"></td>
  <td valign="top"><h2>Title goes here</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="bottom"><b>
    description description description description description description description extra text extra text extra text extra text
  </b></td>
</tr>
...
</tbody></table>
```

This table looks like this in Chrome:

[image: Smashed table in Chrome]

As I remove text from the description, the table regains the appropriate appearance:

[image: Not so smashed table in Chrome]

However, the very same table is always displayed correctly in Firefox:

[image: Never smashed in Firefox]

It seems that WebKit does not respect `margin-right` of the icon, whereas Firefox does. I've tried playing with the description's `td` and `b` tags' styles by changing `display` and `overflow` but without any effect. I've also changed `margin-right` to `padding-right` but without any effect as well.

How can I have WebKit respect the icon's `margin-right`?

I am using Twitter Bootstrap as a CSS framework for my website. I am not using Bootstrap's CSS for this table.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior on Chrome. Can you add any CSS that could be affecting this HTML. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/V9QB9/

Comment: Tables should be used to display tabular data, not for layout purposes.  This doesn't look like tabular data.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff, looks like this problem is caused by Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/YJtS7/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's the bootstrap CSS. This class has `max-width: 100%`, which is the cause:

```css
img {
    width: auto 9;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;  /* the culprit */
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

To get around it, reset `max-width`:

```css
td img {
    margin-right: 2.0em;
    max-width: initial;
}
```

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### CSS:

```css
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

td img {
    margin-right: 2.0em;
    max-width: initial;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><img src="http://placekitten.com/75" /></td>
        <td><h2>Title goes here</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>description description description description description ajdjaslkd lasdjalksjd asjdlasjdlkas asjdklasdjas jaskldja asdjlkasdsjal asjdlksa</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know why `max-width: 100%` prevents WebKit from respecting the image's margin? The CSS reference does not give an indication of this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights

Comment: @SamadLotia No, I don't really understand. `min-width`, `max-width` and `width` all have a similar effect.